# PhpStorm copy deployment excluded paths to another project

Tags: phpstorm, web-deployment

We use [PhpStorm's Deployment tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/deployment.html) to sync changes in our projects.

Since we use frameworks for most projects, *Excluded Paths* settings for Deployment tool is quite repetitive. But despite the fact, excluded paths list is not copy/paste'able, which is a blasphemy for a typical programmer.
It is very tedious to set each path one-by-one and manually.

*You can consider the following screenshot to share my pain;*

[image]

*Thanks, I feel a bit better now.*

**To conclude:** I've been looking for a way to make this process lazier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpStorm creates `.idea` folder in each project folder (*[elsewhere if you set it to be so](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-and-ide-settings.html)*) to hold project settings.

And excluded deployment paths can be found, copied and edited in `.idea/deployment.xml`'s `paths > serverdata > excludedPaths` node.

[image]

You can copy and inject it to some other project to quickly set all default excluded paths in no time, and use the saved time to brew yourself a nice cup of coffee.